# fractional Sobolev integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am trying to compute this limit
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2}}\int_{0}%
^{e^{-1/\varepsilon}}\int_{0}^{e^{-1/\varepsilon}}\frac{\left\vert \frac
{1}{\log x}-\frac{1}{\log y}\right\vert ^{2}}{|x-y|^{2}}dxdy.
$$
I would like to understand if the limit is zero. I tried many changes of
variables (like $t=-\log x$ and $s=-\log y$) but with no luck. This is taken
from a paper, but the computations are skipped, and it is hard to read. An
alternative would be to prove
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2}}\int_{0}%
^{e^{-1/\varepsilon}}\int_{0}^{e^{-1/\varepsilon}}\frac{\left\vert \frac
{1}{(-\log x)^{a}}-\frac{1}{(-\log y)^{a}}\right\vert ^{2}}{|x-y|^{2}}dxdy=0
$$
for some $a>0$ (in case $a$ helps).

Comment: Did the paper assert that the limit is zero? Naive MVT bound gives $O(\varepsilon^{-6})$ which is terrible.

Comment: Yes, it did assert that the one with $a>0$ is zero.

Comment: @dezdichado Could you elaborate on what exactly is the MVT bound you used?

Comment: @Zachary it's just the simple integral version of MVT:

$$\int\int_Af(x,y)dxdy = \text{Area of A } f(x',y')$$ for a compact $A = [\delta, e^{-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}]^2$, but this is way too naive. I am thinking of something like Calderon-Zygmund type estimate for singular kernel right now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is $x', y'$? I'm not very comfortable with MVT